# Complex Pandas Melt

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pandas-melt

I've got a complex melt function that I need to do. I've tried stepping through it and checking other questions, but I am very stuck!

Here is my current dataframe:

```
         1   2   4   5   6   10   24
Userid

u_A      0   1   3   0   0    0    5
u_B      0   0   0   0   0    0    1
```

and I need to get to this:

```
Userid    Movieid    Rating
u_A          2         1
u_A          4         3
u_A          24        5
u_B          24        1
```

So, to clarify, removing 0 valued ratings and having each rating on a separate row, accessible by the Userid. I know that usually the columns axis also has a name (in this case, that series at the top), but I've somehow managed to lose that in my processing.

The closest I got was with the statement `fold_1_df.melt(var_name=' movie_id', value_name=' rating')` but the format is still not complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `0` with `NaN` and then use [`df.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

```
df.rename_axis("movie_id", axis=1).replace(0, np.nan).stack().reset_index(
    name="rating"
)

  Userid movie_id  rating
0    u_A        2     1.0
1    u_A        4     3.0
2    u_A       24     5.0
3    u_B       24     1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `.reset_index()`, melt and set index again. Then filter the dataframe by `rating`:

```
x = (
    df.reset_index()
    .melt(id_vars="Userid", var_name="movie_id", value_name="rating")
    .set_index("Userid")
)
print(x[x["rating"] > 0])
```

Prints:

```
       movie_id  rating
Userid                 
u_A           2       1
u_A           4       3
u_A          24       5
u_B          24       1
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround at this point which looks like this:

```
fold_1_df = fold_1_df.melt(ignore_index = False,var_name=' movie_id', value_name=' rating') 
fold_1_df[fold_1_df[' rating'] != 0]
```